# apk generated showing "There was a problem while parsing the package" on certain device

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I've generated apk using ./gradlew assembleRelease and I tested on my 2 android devices (one has Android version 10 and 8.0.0) and they are working well.

The problem is one of our clients' phone shows "There was a problem while parsing  the package" error when installing the apk generated and the phone's version is 8.1.0 which is higher than one of my android device.

Before the latest generation, it was working fine but after generating new build which includes react-native-linear-gradient library, it shows that.

Since it is working fine on my devices, I'm not sure what is wrong with it. Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reason of: **Problem parsing package error**

1. You might have turned off “Allow installation from unknown resources”
2. The downloaded .apk is not fully downloaded or corrupted
3. The app is not compatible with the Hardware or version of the OS you are using

reference: https://medium.com/@GuruTechnolabs/how-to-fix-problem-parsing-the-package-error-in-android-c2fca91673cb